# iam using Retrofit library to fetch data from Database to recyclerview

Tags: android, http, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

am trying to Fetch the movies data from Mysql DB and show it to Recycler view

but when i run the app nothing shows

here is code i am using Retrofite Library

but i can't parse the Data to the Recycler view

i've made Adapter and Model Class normally like the Json

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String url="http://192.168.1.109/stu/";
    RecyclerView recyclerViewMovies;
    List<MovieListsModels> movies;
    MoviesAdapter adapter;
    TextView Errortxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Errortxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txterror);
        recyclerViewMovies = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerViewMovies.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        loadDatafromServer();
    }

    private void loadDatafromServer() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<MovieListsModels> call = api.ShowMoviesData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieListsModels>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieListsModels> call, Response<MovieListsModels> response) {
                try {
                    MovieListsModels movie = response.body();
                    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, (List<MovieListsModels>) movie);
                    recyclerViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieListsModels> call, Throwable t) {
                Errortxt.setText(t.getMessage().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the interface of the methods

> Api.class Interface

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("config.php")
    Call<MovieListsModels> ShowMoviesData();
}
```

> MovieLists.class

```
public class MovieListsModels {

    public MovieListsModels() {
    }

    int id;
    String movie_name;
    String movie_image;
    String movie_genre;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMovie_name() {
        return movie_name;
    }

    public void setMovie_name(String movie_name) {
        this.movie_name = movie_name;
    }

    public String getMovie_image() {
        return movie_image;
    }

    public void setMovie_image(String movie_image) {
        this.movie_image = movie_image;
    }

    public String getMovie_genre() {
        return movie_genre;
    }

    public void setMovie_genre(String movie_genre) {
        this.movie_genre = movie_genre;
    }

    public MovieListsModels(int id, String movie_name, String movie_image, String movie_genre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.movie_name = movie_name;
        this.movie_image = movie_image;
        this.movie_genre = movie_genre;
    }

}
```

> MovieAdapter.class

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieHolderView>  {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<MovieListsModels> MovieList = new ArrayList<>();
    public MoviesAdapter(Context mContext, List<MovieListsModels> movieList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        MovieList = movieList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieHolderView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
       MovieHolderView holder = new MovieHolderView(view);
       return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieHolderView holder, int position) {
        MovieListsModels list = MovieList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(list.getMovie_name());
        holder.txtGenre.setText(list.getMovie_genre());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(list.getMovie_image())
                .into(holder.imgMovie);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return MovieList.size();
    }

    public class MovieHolderView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName,txtGenre;
        ImageView imgMovie;
        public MovieHolderView(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             txtName =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieName);
             txtGenre =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieGenre);
             imgMovie =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieImg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your device is connected to the same network, since you are using local ip i am confirming

Comment: i use Android Emulator and i did make sure that all the connections are ok

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a list of movies is better because you expect a list, I suppose

```
public void onResponse(Call<MovieListsModels> call, Response<MovieListsModels> response) {
            try {
                List<MovieListsModels> movie = response.body();
                adapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, movies);
```

And I believe that not executing the notifyDataSetChanged, you can added like that:

```
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MovieListsModels> MovieList = new ArrayList<>();
    public MoviesAdapter(Context mContext, List<MovieListsModels> movieList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        MovieList = movieList;
        notifiyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Does movieList even reach the adapter's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having `json response` of the form `{..}`, you are having an object response and you should expect an object as you have done i.e, `Call<YourObject>`

If you are having `json response` of the form `[..]`, you are having an array response and you should expect an array i.e, `Call<List<YourObject>>`

In your case, i hope its an array(*second case*), So make changes as per the above answer done by @Guillodacosta

Answer (score 0):

First don't forget to add the internet permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Second try this

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(list.getMovie_image()).into(holder.imgMovie);
```